# Cant open image from Jupiter notebook - No such file or directory

Tags: python, operating-system, python-imaging-library

I'm trying to read images from a Directory. Ive tried

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

for picute in os.listdir(os.path.join("pics")):
    print(img)
    image = Image.open(img)
    image.resize((224, 224), Image.LANCZOS)
    break
```

but it always gives back a FileNotFoundError (`[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '2021788681540276540.jpg'`) but I am definitely sure it exists (I can open the images from the Jupyter file explorer).

The folder "pics" contains 10 .jpg pictures. The code runs in a Jupiter Notebook in the Amazon Cloud with python 3.6.

Comment: Is the folder `pics` in the current working directory where you run the notebook???

Comment: Yes, the folder is in the same directory.

Comment: Try `image = Image.open(os.path.join("pics", img))`

Comment: Glad I could help!!! I added the answer for other people who have the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was simple, you should pass the relative path to `Image.open()` function like so:

```
import cv2
from PIL import Image

for picute in os.listdir(os.path.join("pics")):
    print(img)
    image = Image.open(os.path.join("pics", img)) #<--- CHANGE TO THIS
    image.resize((224, 224), Image.LANCZOS)
    break
```